# How to interpret posterior distribution plots for multiple priors?

Tags: bayesian, pymc

Let us consider the following Bayesian model:

- $f(x|\mu, \theta)$ the observation model,
- $\pi(\mu, \theta)$ the joint prior distribution,
- $\pi(\mu, \theta|x)$ the posterior distribution.

It is possible to obtain the posterior distribution with a MCMC sampler. Then the posterior distributions can be plotted. Using Python pymc3 [plot_posterior](http://docs.pymc.io/api/plots.html#pymc3.plots.plot_posterior) function for example, two pdf figures would be obtained: one for $\mu$, one for $\theta$. It seems these figures are fairly standard (I saw them too in Matlab documentation), so I doubt this is a pymc3 specific feature.

How do these figures relate to $\pi(\mu, \theta|x)$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would say the model you present has **one** prior for **multiple** parameters (in this case two: $\mu$ and $\theta$). Because there are two parameters, the prior is a **joint** prior. Similarly, there is a single **joint** posterior distribution for the two parameters: $\pi(\mu,\theta|x)$. I'm guessing the software that you refer to produces plots of the two **marginal** posterior distributions,
\begin{equation}
\pi(\mu|x) = \int \pi(\mu,\theta|x)\,d\theta
\end{equation}
and
\begin{equation}
\pi(\theta|x) = \int \pi(\mu,\theta|x)\,d\mu . 
\end{equation}
In order to plot the joint posterior distribution (I'm guessing) you would need a different command.

Comment: I believe this answer is spot on; the only thing I can add to help answer the question is that from the MCMC sampler you should have paired samples for $\mu$ and $\theta$.   You can visualise  $ \pi ( \mu , \theta | x ) $   by doing a 2 variable density plot of these samples something like [this](http://2.bp.blogspot.com/-ZsGCOtScfq8/VATD76-mOpI/AAAAAAAAB3k/etTqFIpXIPY/s1600/hexbin2.png) perhaps